# Yup validate is either String or Array of strings

Tags: javascript, formik, yup

I would like to validate that a field is either a string or an array of strings

Here is a [minimal failing example](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-jmph7?fontsize=14) which happens to use formik but actually I am doing server side validation using yup.

```
  {
    email: yup
      .mixed()
      .oneOf([yup.array().of(yup.string()), yup.string()])
      .nullable()
  }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`oneOf` only works with literal values. Lazy allows you to provide a schema dynamically as shown below

```
{ 
  email: yup.lazy(val => (Array.isArray(val) ? yup.array().of(yup.string()) : yup.string()))
}
```

Comment: This is the valid solution

Answer (score 28):

```js
{
  email: yup.mixed()
    .when('isArray', {
      is: Array.isArray,
      then: yup.array().of(yup.string()),
      otherwise: yup.string(),
    })
}
```

But a set of checkboxes can produce an array, and text input would not. Are you searching for a solution to validate emails divided by separator?

Comment: I'm actually doing server side validation of query params - I just forked a formik example as a way of demonstrating the problem

Comment: Sorry but this does not work, as it requires a `isArray` boolean on the object you validate so that we enter the `then` condition. Using `when("email",{})` does not work either, as it produces some kind of infinite loop.

Comment: Actually this is better, and works with typescript, just omit the first argument in the when method and it will refer to itself.

Answer (score 10):

This YUP simple validation work for my case when Form contains multi-select field and keeping this field as mandatory and at least one option is required to select.

```
 selectOptions: array()
         .min(1, "You can't leave this blank.")
         .required("You can't leave this blank.")
         .nullable()
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though. This is just an array of strings. OP wanted either a string (not in an array) or an array of strings.

Answer (score 3):

David Adler's solution is the working one for me.

Here's a TS-based variant:

```
  from: Yup.lazy<string | string[]>(from => {
    return Array.isArray(from)
      ? Yup.array()
        .of(PathnameValidator.required())
        .required()
      : PathnameValidator.required();
  }),
```

Comment: lazy<string | string[]>() doesn't work