# yup.js object validation, allow any key but values must be string or string array

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I am using https://github.com/jquense/yup#yup

I want to have an object validation schema for:

```js
subObjectField: {
    [thisKeyCanBeAnyString]: string | string[] // allow string or array of strings
}
```

I cannot find an example or a starting point to achieve this, any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yup validate is either String or Array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855869/yup-validate-is-either-string-or-array-of-strings)

Comment: For the value part, but how can I validate that this object `subObjectField` can have 'any keys' ?

Answer (score 2):

I've put together a function which makes this easy:

```
  export const objectOf = (schema) => ({
      name: 'objectOf',
      exclusive: false,
      message: "Object values don't match the given schema",
      test: value => {
        return value === null || Object.values(value).every(schema.isValidSync(value));
      }
    });
```

example:

```
yup.object().test(objectOf(yup.number())).nullable()
```

this successfully passes for `null` and for objects of numbers like `{ foo: 52, bar: -12 }`

Answer (score 0):

Building on Arnošt's answer (which should be marked correct). Here's a typescript version:

```
import type { AnySchema } from 'yup';

export const yupObjectOf = <T extends AnySchema>(schema: T) => ({
  name: 'objectOf',
  exclusive: false,
  message: "Object values don't match the given schema",
  test: (value: null | Record<string, unknown>) => {
    return value === null || Object.values(value)
      .every(() => schema.isValidSync(value));
  }
});
```